# Can't write an Object. Read-only file system

Tags: android, file, object, readonly

I'm trying to save this Object, Inventory, to the internal storage. I have the saving and getting methods in the class itself. When I try and call the save method, I end up with the exception. I had the Exception message write to the Logcat, and here's what I got:

08-04 02:32:23.690: VERBOSE/alex(278): /test (Read-only file system)

The file /test is "Read-only file system", but I had allowed writing external storage in the Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Here's the Inventory class. The last two methods are the save and read methods.

```
    package com.androidbook.inventoryproject;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.util.Log;

public class Inventory implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int numIngred;;
    Ingredient[] ingredients;
    ArrayList ingred = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();

    public Inventory() {
        numIngred = 0;
        ingredients = new Ingredient[numIngred]; 
    }

    public int getNumIngred() {

        return numIngred;
    }

    public String getIngredientName(int n) {
        return ((Ingredient)ingred.get(n)).getName();

    }

    public Ingredient[] getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }

    public Ingredient getIngredient(int n) {
        return (Ingredient)ingred.get(n);
    }

    public void addIngredient(String iname) {
        numIngred++;
        ingred.add(new Ingredient(iname));
    }

    public boolean saveInventory( Inventory inv) {
        File suspend_f = new File("test");
        FileOutputStream   fos  = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos  = null;
        boolean            keep = true;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(suspend_f);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(inv);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            keep = false;
            Log.v("alex", "" + e.getMessage());

        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (oos != null)   oos.close();
                if (fos != null)   fos.close();
                if (keep == false) suspend_f.delete();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { /* do nothing */ }
        }
        return keep;
    }

    public Inventory getInventory() {
        File suspend_f = new File("test");
        Inventory inven = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;

        try{
            fis = new FileInputStream(suspend_f);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            inven = (Inventory)ois.readObject();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            String mess = e.getMessage();

        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null)  
                    fis.close();
                if (ois != null)  
                    ois.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
        }
        return inven;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` lets you write to the SD card, not to the filesystem root. You should try this:

```
File suspend_f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test");
```

This verifies that the file you are using goes into a writable external folder.

EDIT: there is a bunch of other work you should do to verify that the SD card is available and writable. Read the [specs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) to see how to make your file access robust by checking availability.

Comment: Oh, wait, I actually want to write to the filesystem root. How do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You can't.  You can basically only write to your app's private storage area and the external storage.

Comment: @Chris is right. Perhaps if you rooted the device and modified the read-only nature of the root partition you MIGHT be able to do it, but you'd never be able to do it in an unmodified Android device. What could you possibly want to do that requires you specifically write to the root?

Comment: Okay I don't really know what I'm talking about. I don't know what a root is. All I want to do is save this object and access it later in the application! Thanks!

Comment: The filesystem root (like you mentioned before). If all you want to do is save it and access it later then you don't need to write to the filesystem root.